# Giving Password by command line on asking for it by bash script

Tags: linux, bash, powershell, ssh

I am writing a bash script for windows powershell.
I am remotely connecting to server by ssh but the problem is connection needs a password and i have to give it by script.
I tried pipelining too by `echo "password" | ssh user@remote.host`.
But is it still asking for password `user@remote.host's password:`. Is there any way to enter password by command line or bash script only?

Comment: Uh, what? Are you writing a PowerShell script or a bash script?  Also, you cannot pipe into `ssh`'s password prompt by design.  Standard input goes into the shell or command on the remote system.

Comment: ssh goes to some lengths to stop you from doing this. If you want to set up a password less login, there is plenty of info on Google. Here is one site - http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ssh-keygen` to generate a new SSH key pair, and `ssh-copy-id user@machine` to copy it to the remote host.

This will let you log in without a password, and it won't introduce any security issues by passing the password as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Use sshpass to pass password to ssh

```
$ sshpass -p 'password' ssh username@server.example.com
```